# Concatinating strings to list items using for loops in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, string-concatenation

I am pretty new to python3, and lately, I have been practicing with lists and functions.

Here, I stored strings inside a list then passed that list to a function that is supposed to concatenate/add a string, like so:

```
def hello(names):
    for name in names:
        name = "Hello "+name+"!"
    return names


liiist = ["L Lawliet", "Nate River", "Mihael Keehl"]
liiist = hello(liiist)
print(liiist)
```

But instead of getting
`['Hello L Lawliet!', 'Hello Nate River!', 'Hello Mihael Keehl!']`, I just get `['L Lawliet', 'Nate River', 'Mihael Keehl']` **Nothing happened**. Also, PyCharm alerts me that `Local variable 'name' value is not used`

I also experimented with this problem, and it turns out, it **also doesn't work outside of functions**:

```
vars = ["trying", "to", "rewrite", "lists"]
for var in vars:
    var = var + " hello"
print(vars)
```

The output: `['trying', 'to', 'rewrite', 'lists']`

I have already found a way around this problem, but I am not happy that I just found the solution by chance/massive amounts of trial and error. **I think me not understanding why python produced results like these might interfere with my career later on.** Can someone please explain why this happens?

Also, if you're curious, here is the work-around I found:

```
def hello(names):
    counter = 0
    for name in names:
        name = name + " the Great"
        names[counter] = names
        counter += 1
    return names

names = ["L Lawliet", "Nate River", "Mihael Keehl"]
names = hello(names)
print(names)
```

Giving me a more efficient code than the one above can also help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get the above output is by appending to the list as mentioned above by @Andrej Kesely. Another way is to use 'yield' generator that outputs the sequence. Refer to the below code.

```
def hello(names):
    for name in names:
        name = "Hello "+name+"!"
        yield name     # generator that outputs sequence. Yield should be inside loop

liiist = ["L Lawliet", "Nate River", "Mihael Keehl"]
liiist = list(hello(liiist))     # store the yield output in a list when calling the function
print(liiist)
```

Refer to the below snapshot for the output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
def hello(names):
    for name in names:
        name = "Hello "+name+"!"
    return names
```

does effectively nothing, because strings in Python are immutable. One solution is return new list that contains newly created strings, for example:

```
def hello(names):
    rv = []
    for name in names:
        rv.append("Hello "+name+"!")
    return rv


liiist = ["L Lawliet", "Nate River", "Mihael Keehl"]
liiist = hello(liiist)
print(liiist)
```

Prints:

```
['Hello L Lawliet!', 'Hello Nate River!', 'Hello Mihael Keehl!']
```

---

Or you can change the list *in-place* (but in this case, your function doesn't return anything):

```
def hello(names):
    for i, name in enumerate(names):
        names[i] = "Hello "+name+"!"

liiist = ["L Lawliet", "Nate River", "Mihael Keehl"]

hello(liiist)
print(liiist)
```

Prints:

```
['Hello L Lawliet!', 'Hello Nate River!', 'Hello Mihael Keehl!']
```